# routing table What does this mean (brackets in routing table)?

Tags: ip, route

Sorry I couldn't be clearer. I literally don't know the terminology for it. So not only can I not describe it, but I cannot google it either because I dont know the words for it.

See photo:

[image: inside brackets]

Help me understand what those numbers mean inside of those brackets please? [10/0] and [20/0].

Thanks.

Comment: Please *never* paste text as a screenshot. Always paste text as text output as text using the editor's `{}` preformat function. Also, you need to add to your question what device you see this on.

Comment: It appears to be from a Fortigate firewall. Their documentation doesn't explain those numbers but I would guess they are possibly Metric and Weight values for the static route. 

https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/6.4.0/administration-guide/221343/verifying-routing-table-contents-in-nat-mode

Comment: @Zac67 I couldn't as I do not own the device this is on. This is literally the photo I have. Im not sure what you're implying here. I just was trying to find an example of what I was seeing. Mildly confused.

Answer (score 1):

The `FGT1` in the first line seems to indicate a FortiGate. The values in [] brackets indicate the route's administrative distance and metric.

Fortinet documents that output rather poorly but it becomes more obvious when you compare it to the GUI display. You find more details e.g. on https://www.fortinetguru.com/2016/06/viewing-the-routing-table-in-the-cli/.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the default route (0.0.0.0/0) as example, you have two sets of brackets.

- The first brackets shows the routing admin distance: [10/0] on the first and second, and [20/0] on the third.
- The second brackets shows the internal SDWAN priority [20/0], [30/0], etc.

From the shown output, my guess is you have three outbound connections as follows:

1. SDWAN zone, with port1 and port2, with admin distance 10
2. regular interface, port3, with admin distance 20.

This is why you have two best default routes (marked by *> 0.0.0.0/0).
The port3 0.0.0.0/0 route is not best, hence used as backup.

Inside the SDWAN zone, you have two connections (port1 and port2), that have different priorities (20 and 30), which can be used as priority or as wheights, depending on your SDWAN rules.